# When I close and admob interstitial ad, it is going to an unintended activity

Tags: java, android

Good day, what seems to be the problem. In my onAdClosed, i placed "ThirdActivity.class" , but when i close the Admob interstitial ad it goes to a different activity.

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, 3rdActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() { Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded"); }
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) { Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad"); }
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() { Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened"); }
        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() { Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication"); }
    });
     .
     .
     .
     builder.setNeutralButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog coldialog = builder.create();
    coldialog.show();
```

Comment: 3rdActivity - class name can not begin by a digit.

Comment: it is just an example. i edited it. thanks

Comment: Why? You have to list source code to find problem and help you.